# Why the count of messages are not same when I pull messages using gcloud cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

It's very strange.

I use `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull message-blocking-SUB --limit 10` try to pull messages from `message-blocking-SUB` subscription.

Here is the results:

```
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull message-blocking-SUB --limit 10
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   DATA                   │    MESSAGE_ID   │ ATTRIBUTES │                                                                              ACK_ID                                                                              │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"data":"Hello, world! - 1543554888273"} │ 283307349579869 │            │ QV5AEkw2B0RJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNCEGgzXHUHUQ0YdHpndmoLFAJTFFl-VVsJPGh-Y3cPUg4ZdX5lfG9dGgkETHvi4M-dxOksZhg9XBJLLD5-PTJF │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull message-blocking-SUB --limit 10
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   DATA                   │    MESSAGE_ID   │ ATTRIBUTES │                                                                               ACK_ID                                                                               │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555283170"} │ 283307447044599 │            │ XkASTDYHRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUQC1MTUVx1E0wQaV0zdQdRDRlze2ZzaVsTBlNBVXRfURsfWVx-SgVZDhpyemVxbVoXBQdMWlbD5I-Lod0sZhs9XBJLLD5-PTJFQQ │
│ {"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555288172"} │ 283307327268587 │            │ XkASTDYHRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUQC1MTUVx1E0wQaV0zdQdRDRlze2ZzaVsTBlNBVXReURsfWVx-SgVZDhpyemJ3bVgVCQdNVFbD5I-Lod0sZhs9XBJLLD5-PTJFQQ │
│ {"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555293176"} │ 283307486528068 │            │ XkASTDYHRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUQC1MTUVx1E0wQaV0zdQdRDRlze2ZzaVsTBlNBVXRdURsfWVx-SgVZDhpyemV9bF8RCQJDW1bD5I-Lod0sZhs9XBJLLD5-PTJFQQ │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull message-blocking-SUB --limit 10
┌───────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│              DATA             │    MESSAGE_ID   │ ATTRIBUTES │                                                                              ACK_ID                                                                              │
├───────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hello, world! - 1543547000557 │ 283191392654279 │            │ QV5AEkw2B0RJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNMEG4zXHUHUQ0YdHpnd2NYEgkCTFl-VVsJPGh-Y3cPUgwQc35od2xfFwMFTHvi4M-dxOksZhg9XBJLLD5-PTJF │
│ Hello, world! - 1543547015562 │ 283191378142602 │            │ QV5AEkw2B0RJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNMEG4zXHUHUQ0YdHpnd2NYEgkCTFl_VVsJPGh-Y3cPUgwQc35mfWteEQcCR3vi4M-dxOksZhg9XBJLLD5-PTJF │
│ Hello, world! - 1543547020563 │ 283191323745952 │            │ QV5AEkw2B0RJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNMEG4zXHUHUQ0YdHpnd2NYEgkCTFl8VVsJPGh-Y3cPUgwQc35jdm1eFggHR3vi4M-dxOksZhg9XBJLLD5-PTJF │
└───────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡  gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull message-blocking-SUB --limit 10
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   DATA                   │    MESSAGE_ID   │ ATTRIBUTES │                                                                              ACK_ID                                                                              │
├──────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"data":"Hello, world! - 1543554888273"} │ 283307349579869 │            │ QV5AEkw2B0RJUytDCypYEU4EISE-MD5FU0RQBhYsXUZIUTcZCGhRDk9eIz81IChFEAtTE1FcdhNCEGgzXHUHUQ0YdHpndmoLFAJTFFl-VVsJPGh-Y3cPUg4ZdX5lfG9dGgkETHvi4M-dxOksZhg9XBJLLD5-PTJF │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
☁  nodejs-gcp [master] ⚡
```

My message queue has three messages.

I run this command four times. It seems that the result is different for each time.

I expect the results should be always three messages.

I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your subscription only has 3 messages? Your 'data' values shows otherwise.

```
{"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555283170"} │ 283307447044599
{"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555288172"} │ 283307327268587
{"data":"Hello, world! - 1543555293176"} │ 283307486528068
{"data":"Hello, world! - 1543554888273"} │ 283307349579869
Hello, world! - 1543547000557 │ 283191392654279
Hello, world! - 1543547015562 │ 283191378142602
Hello, world! - 1543547020563 │ 283191323745952
```

I suspect some of your confusion is that when you pull the messages without acking them they're not available for some period of time, I believe the default is 10s or so. Pubsub is assuming whatever pulled the messages is still doing work and may ack the message soon. Until that window of time passes you'll only see new messages, or ones whose delivery window has expired.

Comment: em..I can't understand. How can I get the same message count for running that command for each time?

Comment: I publish three messages to the topic. And, there is no subscribers. The messages never ack. So there is no other interference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second comment, you do have a subscriber 'message-blocking-SUB'. In order to see the same results you'll need to wait at least 10+second between each call. You mentioned only sending three messages, are you sure you previously didn't send messages while the subscription was active? For example each one of those 7 messages I provided has a separate message id. Check out your Stackdriver monitoring PubSub section in order to view total unack'd messages.